# Condition (num % 3 === 0): why does it need to compare to 0?

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I have a simple fizzbuzz here:

```
var num = 1;

while (num <= 20) {
    switch(true){
        case(num%3 === 0 && num%5 === 0):
            console.log('fizzbuzz');
            break;
        case(num%3 === 0):
            console.log('fizz');
            break;
        case(num%5 === 0):
            console.log('buzz');
            break;
        default:
            console.log(num);
    }
    num++;
}
```

What is the meaning of the comparison to `0` after the modulus in this line: `num%3===0`?

Why isn't it just `num%3`?

Comment: If a number mod 3 is equal to 0...? What don't you understand?

Comment: I can't find a clear explanation on what that comparison means. Why isn't it just `num%3`?

Comment: `if(num%3)` and `if(num%3==0)` are exact opposites. The former is true when the number isn't divisible, and the latter is true when it is

Comment: Because if `num%3` evaluates to 0, 0 is falsey. Instead you need to check for equality to 0, which would be truthy if divisible.

Comment: FYI: `num%3 == 0` and `!(num%3)` are equivalent - if that helps

Comment: If you need an example: say `x` is 6. `x%3` will be 0. So, if we do `if(x%3)` as you suggested, it would be `if(0)`. Since 0 is falsey, the condition would be false. Instead if we check for equality to 0: `if(x%3==0)` it would evaluate to `if(0==0)` which is true and is correct.

Comment: Can somebody tell me please what is difference between `==` and `===`

Comment: @minigeek http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/5647260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep `num%3` instead of `num%3===0`
, Meaning changes completely beacuse to enter into one of the cases it should be divisible by 3 so if it isn't, it will enter to default case as num%3 won't be equal to 0.
In short we use % operator to check if it is divisible as if answer comes out be 0 if and only if it is divisible i.e. remainder is 0

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that modulus checks for remainder

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose num = 1, num%3 is equal to 1.  so if you evaluate `if(num%3)`  it will evaluate to true.  Whereas if you evaluate `if(num%3===0)` if will evaluate to false.

Moreover, the === ensures you are not allowing any values in case of different types, however in this case, == and === wont make much difference.